# is it possible to overwrite strdup from <string.h> with my own?

Tags: c, gcc, googletest, glibc

I need to do so because I am supposed to stub this function for unit testing.

I am using gcc version 5.4.0.

for a lot of other functions that exist in glibc like memcpy I simply wrote the implementation in my  .c file and then this implementation was the one used instead of the original, but in case of strdup and some other function I get a compilation error like this one:

```
error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘__extension__’
 char* strdup (const char *__s)
```

I know this is because I am trying to use a function name that already exist in string.h although it works with some other functions in their as well. I wish to know if it is possible to bypass this somehow.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like in your case the original `strdup` is a preprocessor macro, not an actual function. You can try to get rid of it:

```
#undef strdup
char *strdup(const char *s) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: I just tried it and it allowed me to compile without errors, but it still used the original implementation instead of the stub. I tried to stub __strdup  as well and it acted the same.

Comment: My apologies, it did actually work I had another problem that caused a segmentation fault and since I was passing a null pointer to "strdup" it made me think that the problem still persist.